# How can i use string interpolation in ngClass in Angular 11?

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-class

How can achive it that the class name will be forexample "table1-RED" According to color property.It has color property.(I use not the base material table and this has color property of element.Maybe the angular-material is has also i dont know.I just wanted to say not this the problem).I have more hundred row like this and I want to make it dynamically.Angular 11.

```
   <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table__header">Id</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" ngClass="table1-{{element.color}}"  >{{ element.id }}</td>
      </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me

```
[ngClass]="'table1-'+ element.color"
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ngClass]="'table1-'+ element.color"
```

or

```
[class]="'table1-'+ element.color"
```